# Type casting in C# for xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, casting, xamarin

I want to convert NSMutableArray to CLLocationcoordinates2D[]

I tried the following but it gave me an error ,(this kind of type case is not allowed)

```
NSMutableArray* arrtest ;

// I had added some CLLocationcoordinates2D objects to this

CLLocationcoordinates2D[] locations = (CLLocationcoordinates2D[])arrtest
```

How could I convert?

Answer (score 0):

If you really have an `NSArray` which you need to cast in a C# array, do the following:

```
var locations = NSArray.FromArray<CLLocationCoordinate2D>(arrtest);
```

However, considering that all Apple APIs in Xamarin.iOS return a C# array instead of an `NSArray`, you rarely need this. If you created the NSMutableArray yourself, I'd suggest to use a `List< CLLocationCoordinate2D>` instead.

Comment: I have to write the array of Lats&Longs to a file since I am new to C#  (I am a native ios developer), I thought of calling WriteToFile method on NSArray,,,